# how to fill items into two columns in Jinja2 template

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I have a list of phones dicts, and I want to break it into 2 columns. I have some solution but it looks dirty. What's the right and simplest way to do it?

My solution is here:

myphones dict is here:

```
    myphones = [
{'number':'13888888881',
'fee' = '1'},


{'number':'13888888882',
'fee' = '1'},

{'number':'13888888883',
'fee' = '1'},

{'number':'13888888884',
'fee' = '1'},

{'number':'13888888885',
'fee' = '1'},

{'number':'13888888886',
'fee' = '1'},
]
```

in the templates:
I write:

```
<pre>

{% for phone in myphones %}
<tr>
  <td>
    {{phone.number}}
  </td>
  <td>
    {{phone.fee}}
  </td>

  <td>
    {{phone.number}}
  </td>
  <td>
    {{phone.fee}}
  </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</pre>
```

It like this:

[image]

Comment: You can also use a namedtuple to store the data.

Comment: Can you give me an example? Thank you

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple
You can read about them here. It basically allows you to create a class. With increasing code complexity, this dict notation of storing data might become a bit messy, I personally think a namedtuple would make the code cleaner. It's certainly something you might wanna look into, if not for this case but you might find use for it later. If it's just a key value pair of data like in this one, dict is great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
{% for i in range(0, ((myphones|length)/2)|int, 2) %}
    <tr>
      <td>
        {{myphone[i].number}}
      </td>
      <td>
        {{myphone[i].fee}}
      </td>
      {% if (i+1) <= (myphone|length-1)%}
      <td>
        {{myphone[i+1].number}}
      </td>
      <td>
        {{myphone[i+1].fee}}
      </td>
      {% endif %}
    </tr>
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: It will raise `OutOfIndex` if `len(myphtones)` is an odd number.

Comment: myphones|length)/2|round  is float type
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: @Theodoros Vasileiadis,In python3,`{% for i in range((myphones|length)/2|round) %}` has  TypeError.Like this:  'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: See my updated answer. Maybe casting to int will do it.

Comment: @Theodoros Vasileiadis ,I have tried this too.But the same error.
`app\templates\index.html", line 38, in block "content"
Open an interactive python shell in this frame{% for i in range((myphones|length)/2|int) %}
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

Comment: `{% for i in range(((myphones|length)/2)|int) %}` will work well

Comment: Great, mark it as the answer of this question then. Glad I helped.

Comment: @Theodoros Vasileiadis,a new problem.
I want to show like
13888881,1|13888882,1
13888883,1|13888884,1
13888885,1|13888886,1
But now show as
13888881,1|13888882,1
13888882,1|13888883,1
13888883,1|13888884,1

Comment: Then you need to add a step to range, see my answer now.

Comment: What is the output now?

Comment: I modify `{% for i in range(0, ((myphones|length)/2)|int, 2) %}` into {% for i in range(0, ((myphones|length))|int, 2) %}`
and `loop.index0` into `i`,all the data shows normal,thank you